# Storing dynamically generated grids in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, nosql

I am having some issues trying to come up with the best way to store dynamically generated grids in a database. My current scenario is that I have 2 user roles, to simplify we'll just call them an Admin and a Client.

An admins job is to create plans that need to be filled out by clients in a grid / table on a website. My issue comes in because these plans can be vastly different. Different amount of rows, different amount of columns, different row names, different column names etc.

Another thing for me to think about is that clients can share the same plan so a plan will need to be stored as a template somewhere to be able to share across multiple clients.

I have come up with a few options:

1. Create a 'template' table, a 'row' table, and a 'column' table. With the relationship of template has many rows and rows have many columns. I could then store the users entered data against a row id and a column id.
2. Store the data in a NoSQL database with a templates collection and a user data collection. (I have very little NoSQL experience I am a .Net MSSQL dev so this option may just sound completely stupid)

One other thing that is also a possibility is as a client is filling out their grid (it could span over a few weeks) I need the ability for an admin to add and remove columns and rows if they have forgotten something or believe something isn't relevant anymore and for it to reflect on the clients side of things.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or even tell me my approach is horrible wrong and suggest something better I would be very appreciative!

Comment: My suggestion is: XML or JSON. I don't know which language you are using, but with C# you can use a simple DataSet to get the XML and the Schema. This allows you to rebuild a fitting DataSet with one line and load a fitting XML with the second line of code. Doing so you can separate the structure and the working data.

Comment: Hey @Shnugo sorry I don't fully understand would you be able to go into a bit more detail? To give you more detail I am using C# Web API with a web front end where the data will be displayed / filled out. Are you suggesting storing the template in XML/JSON in a database as well as storing a copy of that XML/JSON per client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked me in a comment to go *a bit more in detail* I'll try. The problem is, that your question is not really *in detail*... So some rather general hints:

SQL Server stores XML not as the string you see but within a hierarchically organized table. Dealing with this data on SQL level needs some know-how, but is astonishingly well performing. If you do the hard work in C#, this will not bother you...

From one of my running projects I can show you an example:

This is the working data

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <YourGrid>
    <YourGridRow>
      <RowID>1227c0fe-cc33-416f-bb99-e03e66b907d4</RowID>
      <ShortText>YourGrid 1</ShortText>
      <Message>NotizBody1</Message>
      <DateFrom>2013-06-24T00:00:00</DateFrom>
      <DateTo>2013-06-25T00:00:00</DateTo>
    </YourGridRow>
    <YourGridRow>
      <RowID>3c0faf74-63d9-4b83-8858-972e7f3c643d</RowID>
      <ShortText>YourGrid 2</ShortText>
      <Message>NotizBody2</Message>
      <DateFrom>2013-06-24T00:00:00</DateFrom>
      <DateTo>2013-06-25T00:00:00</DateTo>
    </YourGridRow>
  </YourGrid>
</Data>
```

The corresponding scheme can be created out of a C# `DataSet` with one single line of code and will tell the engine everything about data types, nullability and so on.

Doing this, you can define different grids (even multi-band!) and store them in a `Grid` table (together with an XML column `GridSchema`, where you store the structural information).

The working data lives in a table `GridData`, with an FK to the corresponding `Grid` and an XML column `Content`.

With the `System.Data.DataSet` you can first define the internal structure of the dataset by loading the schema and then you can populate it by loading the content. Bind this dataset to a grid control and store the changed data as one single XML back to the content column (or to a new row in `GridData` which would keep versions of your old data - if needed).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hey @Shnugo this has helped a heap! Sorry I was a bit confused about the workflow between storing the XML and how to transfer it to/from a DataSet in C# in your original comment but this answer is great Thank you very much for your help.